# Jetpack compose new source is not working

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

I have already tried Jetpack compose with old prebuild source. But recently I downloaded a new source and it isn't working for me. Here is what I have tried.

> I have added source in 
>    Project/androidx_prebuilts/out/ui/build/support_repo/androidx

below androidx directory, I have [compose](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/compose/) and [ui](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/) directories for the source

> Module level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url "$androidx_home/out/ui/build/support_repo/" }
    google()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.compose.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
//           typeuseIR = true
            freeCompilerArgs += "-P"
            freeCompilerArgs +=
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin:syntax=FCS"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.41"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2"

    implementation "androidx.compose:compose-runtime:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-animation:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-animation-core:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-android-view:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-android-view-non-ir:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-android-text:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-core:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-framework:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-layout:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-material:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-platform:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-text:1.0.0-alpha01"


    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1"
}
```

> Application level gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.41"
    ext.androidx_home = project.properties["androidx.home"] ?: "$projectDir/androidx_prebuilts"
    repositories {
        maven { url "$androidx_home/out/ui/build/support_repo/" }
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap"
        }

        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha09'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea.module {
    excludeDirs += file('$projectDir/androidx_prebuilts')
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/"
        }
        maven { url "$androidx_home/out/ui/build/support_repo/" }

        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Error I'm getting while building the project

```
  * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose:compose-runtime:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-animation:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-animation-core:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-android-view:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-android-view-non-ir:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-android-text:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-core:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-framework:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-layout:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-material:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-platform:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.ui:ui-text:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, refer to this doc : [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/README.md)

**"This section describes how to set up your local work environment to build the Android source files. You must use Linux or macOS; building under Windows is not currently supported." — Android Docs**

> Step 1:

First, we need to install Repo from (if not installed)
https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading

and hit below command in your command line

```
mkdir bin 
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Now check `repo status`

> Step 2:

Create a directory lets say "AndroidCompose"

```
mkdir ~/AndroidCompose
cd ~/AndroidCompose
```

and setup git config like (if not setup)

```
git config — global user.name “Your Real Name”
git config — global user.email “you@example.com”
```

Now initialise repo

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b androidx-master-dev
```

The repo is now initialized and if we look in the ~/AndroidCompose directory we will see a “.repo” listing

hit

`ls -a ~/AndroidCompose/.repo`

**"Now your repository is set to pull only what you need for building and running AndroidX libraries. Download the code (and grab a coffee while we pull down 6GB)" -Android Docs**

> Step 3:
>   Command to get all required source

```
repo sync -j8 -c
```

(it’s similar to git fetch)

Now we have downloaded the correct version of Android JetPack source which contains @Composable

This places all the Jetpack Compose source in the "ui" directory

```
cd ~/AndroidCompose/frameworks/support/ui
```

hit

`./studiow` 
to start Android studio

**Be careful when restarting Android Studio. We need to always start from this directory to get the Jetpack Compose libraries.**

Accept the license agreement when prompted. Now we are ready to edit, run, and test!

Comment: Here I have published an article on [Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/mindful-engineering/saying-hello-to-jetpack-compose-a96d9e9c4f77) for more details

Answer (score 1):

jetpack compose UI component build is available as dev version now.
you do not have to use Special android studio. Just include all your compose Gradle dependencies with '0.1.0-dev01' as version

Update: Now Android Studio 4.0 canary comes with Jetpack Compose and live preview, out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem then I found a solution that worked well for me.
I am sharing that URL with you.

https://github.com/Mishkun/try-compose

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I already tried the above example but it contains an old source which I have already set up, for new source I have found a way. I'll post it as an answer.